# Can't use a try/catch to test if audio is valid in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that lets users change the default sound notification and I'm now trying to validate the audio link the user submits. The default sound, which I created with a normal HTML element (document.createElement) plays audio fine. When I run the following code (where inp represents a text input and audio represents the original audio object), I get an unsupported source DOM error:

```
try {
    let newAudio = document.createElement("audio");
    newAudio.src = inp.value;
    newAudio.play();
    audio = newAudio;
}
    catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

I've tried all kinds of variations but nothing seems to work: creating newAudio as a JS audio object, reading the duration/readyState value of the audio object, etc. Again, nothing works and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by input text form, but I do not think input element has an innerHTML. You are probably looking for inp.value

Comment: I've changed it (although I believe when I debugged with innerHTML I was getting the right URL)--value gives the same error

Comment: Hi @khajiit can you maybe set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can try to see what you mean without putting a lot of effort into setting up the dev environment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.play()` returns a promise. Try putting the keyword `await` in front of `newAudio.play()`?

Comment: @JiFus Thanks for the suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/wc2gys18/. I just learned HTML/CSS/JS this week, so apologiess in advance for unconvential code. For reference, the code in question begins at line 108.

Comment: Hi @khajiit did you happen to forget to put some HTML code in your fiddle?

Comment: @JiFus Just attached now!

Comment: @khajiit The fiddle is an evolving snippet. After you save the snippet you get a new URL, could you paste it here?

Comment: @JiFus Thanks for the heads up, here's the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/btj651sx/. The HTML is for another website, the JS is a script I'm running in Tampermonkey.